# Date not appearing in document class 'proc'

Tags: titles, date

I am viewing it with pdflatex.

I could not understand the other question's solution

```
\documentclass[12pt]{proc}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Bus Rapid Transit}
\author{Mohamed Mirza}
\date{May 9, 2018} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

A common phenomenon that has repeatedly been experienced by humanity is 
urbanization. Urbanization, which happens to share the same suffix as 
modernization and industrialization, represents the expanding number of 
individuals that populate urban areas, e.g. cities and suburbs. Currently, 
over 54\% of the entire human population lives within urban areas and that 
number is only expected to increase in the coming years. Following this 
population shift from rural to urban areas, cities within the Twenty-First 
Century face a plethora of problems at unprecedented levels. 

A current problem faced by densely populated cities revolves around traffic 
congestion. Traffic congestion is dynamic since it negatively affects 
several components of society. Public transportation systems suffer 
directly en masse as a result of traffic congestion. 

Transportation systems are central to fueling a city's economic 
productivity and can influence positive socio-economic environment changes 
that lead to community development. Hence, there has been a growing 
interest from federal governments and academic institutions to study and 
examine how different forms of transportation systems react to traffic 
congestion in an attempt to better design and replace aging infrastructure 
to serve stakeholders. In order to examine how a Bus Rapid Transit system, 
also represented by the acronym \textbf{\emph{BRT}}, can benefit cities, it 
is important to first understand what a transportation system is and its 
effect on economic, social, and physical systems. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, the `proc` class does not use the date in its `\maketitle` command. You would need to redefine the underlying macro `\@maketitle` to use `\@date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the next code into the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \vbox to 2.25in{%
    \hsize\textwidth
    \linewidth\hsize
    \vfil
    \centering
    {\LARGE \@title \par}
    \vskip 2em
    {\large \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author\end{tabular}\par}
    \vskip 1em
    \@date\par
    \vfil}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to LaTeX and don't understand what preamble is

Comment: Before `\begin{document}`

Comment: nothing happens - something is definitely missing